# How to support properly kernel suspend/resume feature in kernel driver?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, suspend

I have a kernel driver with char device :

```
static const struct file_operations xxxxx_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = xxxxx_read,
};
```

A read callback on this char device :

```
static int XXXX_read(struct file *filp, char __user *data, size_t len, loff_t *ppos)
{
    int err = 0;
    int retry = 0;

    do {
        if (retry == 5) return -3;
        err = down_interruptible(&priv.XXXX_sem);
        if (err == 0) {
            retry = 0;
            break;
        } else {
            retry++;
            continue;
        }
    } while (1);

    err = copy_to_user(data, &priv.XXXX_queue[priv.XXXX_read_offset], XXXX_TOTAL_SIZE);
    priv.XXXXX_read_offset += XXXXX_TOTAL_SIZE;
    if (priv.XXXX_read_offset == XXXX_QUEUE_SIZE) priv.XXXX_read_offset = 0;
    if (err) printk ("Error during XXXX copy\n");
    return (XXXX_TOTAL_SIZE - err);
};
```

In my userland code, I open the char device and use read call in a loop :

```
(...)
while (1)
{
    err = read (fd, &ctx->xxxx_queue[xxxxx_offset], XXXX_TOTAL);
    if (err != XXXX_TOTAL)
    {
        PRINT_WARN ("XXXX read byte : %d (errno : %d)", err, errno);
        continue;
    }
    (...)
}
(...)
```

Everything is running fine.

When I used suspend feature from the kernel by calling :
**echo mem > /sys/power/state**, an issue occured on resume :
**XXXX read byte : -1 (errno : 3)**
At this moment most of the time my driver read callback is block
in the semaphore wait (**down_interruptible**)

The read return -1 on kernel resume. Is there a way to avoid this ?
I tried to looking for a suspend/resume callback to declare on
struct file_operations but nothing.
Do I have just to ignore -3 error fro ioctl ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code of `->read()` callback implementation in your driver.

Comment: @0andriy I just add the code to the initial post and I am stupid. Just the fact to add the read callback and the action to explain my issue on StackOverflow, I think that I get the problem here. Probably that resume of the board, trigger a userland event catch by down_interruptible. I don't know if I must use **down** instead of **down_interruptible** or if I must catch resume event to inhibit them.